# How to replace periods after all caps words?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working with a textual dataset that requires some cleaning, and I need to replace a specific pattern set. Namely, I need to replace periods with colons following only words of len > 1 which contain only capitalized letters.

I've already tried using regex for this but I can't get it to replace only the period.

Ideally, I'd like to have a function doing the following:

```
s = "this is a CITATION. AUTHOR, information GOES here AnD. this P. period isn't replaced."
s = corr(s)
s = "this is a CITATION: AUTHOR, information GOES here AnD. this P. period isn't replaced."
```

But what I've already tried:

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'[A-Z]+\.',':',s)
```

Replaces the occurrence itself with a colon which isn't what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex with word-boundary `\b` and quantifier `{2,}` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qRdyXA/2)):

```
import re

s = "this is a CITATION. AUTHOR, information GOES here AnD. this P. period isn't replaced."

print( re.sub(r'(\b[A-Z]{2,})\.', r'\1:', s) )
```

Prints:

```
this is a CITATION: AUTHOR, information GOES here AnD. this P. period isn't replaced.
```